# Looking for an svn

Tags: svn

Im looking for an svn that would allow moderation (no one can SEE commit until i accept it), easy integration into the existing user / ACL scheme.

the users should not be allowed to comunicate in any way without moderation.

is there something i can use (i have little expirence with svns) or would i have to (shiver) write my own ?

EDIT : clarification - i want software for linux :P

Comment: @Archimedix "Subversion" version control system, I suppose

Comment: As soon as users know each other, there are ways to communicate with one another and exchange their work.

Comment: the point is for users NOT to know each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion (SVN) is a particular version control system; commits are always executed against a central server.

There are "mods" / hacks for that which introduce partial distributed / decentralized versioning to it (such as svk), but I'd rather use a genuine distributed version control system (DVCS) like git or so where every developer can have a separate repository.

In DVCS, you could have an "official" branch where only particular developers can write to (I guess this could be done using pre-commit hooks on the primary "authoritative" / "official" server or with special mechanisms provided by the DVCS).

You would then have guidelines saying that developers should only check out / fetch from the authoritative server when starting work on something.

Regarding access control, it's hard to say something about it without more information about your particular needs, but any VCS that supports access through an SSH or web server should make it possible to use authentication modules available for Linux or the web server.

Comment: my need is that no one can send anything to one another without moderation. i understand that commits are executed against a central server but can i put them into a UNREADABLE queue ?

Comment: I don't know of any practical way to implement an unreadable queue for SVN or DVCS but using a DVCS you might be able to redirect reads and writes to different repositories so that developer commits go to one repo but checkouts / fetches come from the other, which is probably over-complicated. I think it is better to use policies and guidelines - you have to put some trust in your developers anyway (or would you employ outright malicious devs). Each developer would only commit to his own branch and push these changes to the authoritative server, and you could then merge them into the mainline.

Comment: ok, this doesnt solve the problem, but then only writing it myself will i guess. so i accept this, as its the best answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an SVN server then have a look at VisualSVN Server: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Answer (score 0):

No need to write your own implementation. Rather check out different SVN Server providers such as [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com).

But from what I understand about having final word about commits, you chould check out other systems also, such as Git/GitHub. Take a look at [Distributed Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control).

Comment: the system needs to be integrated into a project and if its not fully moderated - its out. i consider that not lack of functionality but in this case a security flaw